# Having Netbeans autodeploy war file to tomcat

Tags: java, jsp, netbeans, tomcat6, netbeans-6.9

Greetings all

Currently working on assessing a project, and wondered if there was a way to have it so the war file generated whe the project is built can be autodeployed to a specified directory to be used by tomcat. I'm using netbeans 6.9.1 on ubuntu 10, with tomcat 6, and while I figured there was a way to do this in the application, for the life of me I've been unable to find it.

Thanks in advance to anyone that can shed some light on how to do this (or if it is possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in 2 ways :

1. Create a ant target that will copy and paste your war file in tomcat webapps
2. Create and target that will configure tomcat to look for war file in your project's target so your purpose will get solved

Comment: Thanks for the reply, and apologies for the delay in confirming.